# Value too large for defined data type

Tags: php, readfile

I'm using readfile() in a php download script.

When I try to download a 9gb sized file, I get the following error:

```
function.readfile</a>]: failed to open stream: Value too large for defined data type in path of my file
```

Is it possible to fix it or do I have to move those files to the public_html directory and link them directly?

Comment: wow, parsing 9GB with php? maybe wrong tool for the job~?

Comment: @Shad // can't agree more, but what can i do..i have to fix it

Comment: @Shad //um.. well...it is not parsing actually. it is reading* and sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can hack a way though.  If you are on a unix environ, you can do

`passthru('cat $filename');`

as long as you don't need to write

Comment: @Jermy Walton // one more question...as @Shad implied, I'm worrying about the server memory. Is it okay to use passthru with cat command to download files? How is it diff from downloading a file via apache server?

Comment: You don't have to worry about memory, as the stdin/stdout buffer is of fixed length.  Once cat has filled it, it has to wait until php takes some off to send more.  The file is not entirely in memory.  This is not something you want to do all the time, because spawning a process to handle this is expensive.  Its different than sending it directly from the apache server is because apache will send the file faster and with less overhead, than php will.  Always send the file via apache first, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to re-compile php with `CFLAGS="-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"` so that PHP is able to handle large files. There's comment about that on the [`fopen` documentation page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#37791).

Some additional reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support
- Althought you might not be using SUSE, still some interesting information: [http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html](http://www.suse.de/%7Eaj/linux_lfs.html)

Comment: Deschences // Thank you for the answer. Is there any other ways ? We can change php.ini, but recompiling is not an option. Also, Brad G on the php.net mentioned that CFLAGS can cause an issue. http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#37791

Comment: @Moon - That is correct. Unfortunately, there is no other way that I'm aware of. I ran into a similar issue a while back (except it was with large flat file databases).

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes is there an easy way to fix this if we install from a repository? Opposed to compiling from scratch?

Comment: @Chris - Sorry for not replying sooner. I'm not aware of any ways to fix this other than recompiling.

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes thanks and no need to apologize!  I was under the gun, we ended up just rebuilding the server with 64 bit OS.  :-)