# performance of passthru("cat file")

Tags: php, performance, passthru

I'm using passthru("cat filepath") in my download script. My concern is that it might use a lot of server resource.

What is the difference between directly link a file in a public directory and download a file using passthru("cat filepath") in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between directly link a file in a public directory and download a file using passthru("cat filepath") in php?

The difference is that linking directly to a file does not invoke PHP, while running a PHP script which in turn runs `cat` causes, well, both PHP and `cat` to be invoked.  This will take up a moderate amount of extra memory, but won't cause *server load* under most circumstances.

> I was using readfile(), but this function can't be used for files larger than 2gb

You might want to find a better solution than passing all of the file contents through PHP, in that case.  Look into [X-Sendfile](http://www.google.com/search?q=x-sendfile) support in your web server software of choice.

Comment: // Thank you for the suggestion. I've learned a new thing here. X-Sendfile! I will look for it.

Comment: // also..thank you for the performance suggestion. I was worrying about passthru causing a lot of load on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `passthru()` for that, you're opening yourself to **CLI Injection** and performance is terrible. [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) exists just for that.

```
readfile($filepath);
```

There is a small overhead when passing through PHP compared to a direct link but we are usually talking of milliseconds. However, the browser will not be able to request a `206 Partial` when using `readfile()` unless you code support for it or use something like [`PEAR::HTTP_Download`](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Download).

**EDIT:** Seems you are using `passthru()` because apparently `readfile()` doesn't handle >2GB files properly (I never had that problem with `readfile()`, in fact I just tested it with a 7.2 GB file and it worked fine). In which case, at least escape your parameters.

```
function readfile_ext($filepath) {
  if(!file_exists($filepath))
    return false;

   passthru('cat ' . escapeshellarg($filepath));
   return true;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Moore // see my comment on deceze's post.

Comment: @Andrew Moore // Thank you for the suggestion. I will escape the variable.

Comment: @Moon: Note that I never had that 2GB problem with `readfile()`. Where did you read about that limitation? Did you test it?

Comment: @Andrew Moore // I've encountered an error with a large file. My previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463586/value-too-large-for-defined-data-type

Comment: @Andrew Moore // also, http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php#37791 this is fopen function doc., but it looks like it applies to readfile as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `passthru('cat filepath')`, use the PHP native `readfile('filepath')`, which has better performance.

Both methods will be slower than simply directly linking to the file though, since PHP has a certain overhead.

Comment: // i was using readfile(), but this function can't be used for files larger than 2gb

Comment: Serving a 2GB file via PHP is not very ideal to begin with. Do you require any PHP here? Couldn't your web server handle it directly?

Comment: // the files can't be placed in a public directory. I put files a private  directory. So..I can't link them directly.